# How could I do this and tried a thousand ways, any advice? I'm new to flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

that after pressing the button it is displayed, something like a horizontal drawer

[image]

that after pressing the button it is displayed, something like a horizontal drawer¿????

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCY40.jpg)

Comment: use `showModalBottomSheet()`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.